# Change / Revert back some elements by jquery dependending on what button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a list and some thumbnails inside. 
The (simplified) html of each *li* when the page loads:

```
<a class="img" href="http://exemple.com">
   <img src="http://exemple.jpg" onmouseover="startFlipBook(...);" onmouseout="endFlipBook(...);">
</a>
```

In that page, I have an "Edit" Button. When I click on that button, I load the jquery UI sortable plugin (so the user is able to sort the list). With javascript, I remove the *mouseover* and the *mouseout* on the images. I also disable the click on all *a href*. I do:

```
$("#edit").click(function() {
    $( "img" ).removeAttr('onmouseover').removeAttr('onmouseout');
    $( "a, .wrap" ).css('cursor','move');
    $( "a").click(function(){return false;});
});
```

So far, it's working like I want (not sure it's the best way of doing it though).

Now, in edit mode, I have a "Cancel" button. Hitting that button should put back the *mouseover* and the *mouseout* on the images, and the links need to work again.

This is where my code is not woking. I do :

```
$("#cancel").click(function() {
    //No idea how I can get back my initial mouseover and mouseout with the correct parameter        
    $( "a, .wrap" ).css('cursor','auto');
    $( "a" ).click(function(){return true;});
});
```

The links stay unclickable, the cursor is wrong and I don't know how to put back my *mouseover* event.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attribute from all 'a' HTML element.

```
<a class="img" href="http://example.com">
    <img src="http://example.jpg">
</a>
```

In the script you can use this sollution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Add mouseenter and mouseleave event listener 
    $("a.img")
        .mouseenter(function(){ startFlipBook(...); })
        .mouseleave(function(){ endFlipBook(...); });

    // When click on Edit button
    $("#edit").click(function(){

        // Remove the mouseenter and mouseleave event listener
        $("a.img").unbind("mouseenter").unbind("mouseleave");
        $("a, .wrap").css('cursor','move');
        $("a").click(function(){return false;});
    });

    // When click on Cancel button
    $("#cancel").click(function() {

        // Add mouseenter and mouseleave event listener
        $("a.img")
            .mouseenter(function(){ startFlipBook(...); })
            .mouseleave(function(){ endFlipBook(...); });
        $( "a, .wrap" ).css('cursor','auto');
        // Remove the click event listener
        $( "a" ).unbind("click");
    });
});
```

You can read more about jQuery functions, what i wrote above:

[unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) : Remove an event listener
[mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/): Add an event listener, when mouse enters into an area
[mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/): Add an event listener, when mouse leaves an area

Comment: That fixed my link problem thanks! Ill see if I can move the mouseenter event outside the anchor...!

Answer (score 1):

In your "cancel" click function...

```
$('a').unbind('click');
```

This will unbind the click function that is returning false (disabling your link).

Comment: The parameters of the flipbook function are different on each <li>... And do you know why the links are still not clickable even if I do return true ?